# Is this corollary true: If G is k-regular with k $\geq 1$, then G has a 1-factor.

Tags: graph-theory

> Corollary 2.1.4. If G is k-regular with $k \geq 1$, then G has a 1-factor.

This corollary is in textbook titled 'Graph Theory' by R. Diestel, p.33.

I have a problem with this corollary. i.e. Suppose that G is with 5 vertices, the G is cyclic connected graph where each vertex is incident with 2 vertices (see the figure) so that G is a 2-regular graph. Now, if we applies the corollary, then this graph must has a 1-factor. However, this is not true, because this graph doesn't have a 1-factor since the number of vertices is odd. My question is: Is this corollary is true or it needs more details for example it should have more information about the number of vertices. So, it should say:

> Corollary. If G is k-regular with k $\geq 1$ and number of vertices is even, then G has a 1-factor.

What I'm saying is that the corollary in textbook isn't enough, because it doesn't tell about the number of vertices, therefore it is wrong. Is my conclusion true?

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: @bof see this link (http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf) see page 33. Before the corollary, the author gives only proof of Hall's theorem. He give this corollary (2.1.4) as an example to show that using Hall's theorem we can prove a lot of theorems. I didn't thought about your example 2-regular graph on 6 vertices has no 1-factor but this makes my edited corollary is also not enough. Furthermore, I understand that you agree that if the author doesn't mention a bipartite graph before the corollary, then his corollary isn't enough, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right. It is not true that a $k$-regular graph ($k\gt1$) must have a $1$-factor. Your example $C_5$ shows this. A smaller counterexample is the graph $C_3$ also known as $K_3.$
2. Assuming that the graph has an even number of vertices does not help. The graph $2K_3$ (two disjoint triangles) is a $2$-regular graph with $6$ vertices, and has no $1$-factor.
3. Assuming that the graph is *connected* and has an even number of vertices does not help. There is a connected $3$-regular graph on $16$ vertices which has no $1$-factor; see the figure in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520203/k-regular-simple-graph-without-1-factor/520335#520335).
4. On the other hand, every $k$-regular *bipartite* graph (where $k\ge1$) does have a $1$-factor.
5. I found a copy of Diestel's book. Corollary 2.1.4 is on p. 33, in section 2.1, titled "Matching in bipartite graphs". The first sentence of section 2.1, on p. 29, reads as follows:

> For this whole section, we let $G=(V,E)$ be a fixed bipartite graph with bipartition $\{A,B\}.$

Comment: Ahh, so for any bipartite graph that is k-regular (k $\geq 1)$, then it must have a 1-factor. Now, I understand. I have a question: there is a proposition in the same book: 1.6.1 says: A graph is bipartite graph iff it contains no odd cycles. Now, if I say "if G is not odd cycle and regular graph, then it has a 1-factor". does that mean that no.3 in your answer that says 3-regular graph on 16 vertices must contain odd cycle?

Comment: This is my mistake, I was meaning that "if G doesn't contain odd cycle and it is regular graph, then it has a 1-factor" just as you did in your comment. Thank you for your answer, it really helps me understand the big picture. Have a nice holiday :)